# Componentart grid alternative

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web, datatables, componentart

Does anyone perhaps know of a good alternative to use for component art grid ? I have a situation where the viewstate for one page is 1.5MB as a result of a grid with 1800 rows that have to be clientside because they are editable and the result is all postbacks on the page are really slow because all that viewstate needs to be uploaded.

So I'm considering replacing the componentart grid with some alternative such as http://www.datatables.net/ , I love that grid but unfortunately I need more functionality such as expandable rows, up to three levels. This is also amazing http://www.ext.net/ , but the licences are quite expensive and not sure if my requirements are for a whole framework when I just need one grid. Are there any other client side tables/grid you could reccoment ?

Here is an example of the current solution (censored sensitive info ) :
[image: grid example]

Answer (score 2):

Jq grid CAN be good option for u .....here is the link....

[http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html..](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

Comment: This is definitely an option thanks, I will investigate this one and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Try [DevExpress](http://devexpress.com).. Its not free but this one of the best tools around..

http://demos.devexpress.com/RWA/WebmailClient/

Answer (score 1):

You could treat the client-side grid as a window into the whole grid, loading & saving only the values that are currently displayed.